# URLRewriter rewrites all requests, even for images

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm using [URLRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/), but there is a problem, it re-write all addresses, even for image URLs, for example, it shows a webpage for http://localhost/images/logo.png.

It's my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

    <configSections>
      <section name="rewriter"
               requirePermission="false"
               type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
    </configSections>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

      <httpModules>
        <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
      </httpModules>

    </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule" />
    </modules>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  </system.webServer>

  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/pages/(.+)" to="~/default.aspx?pn=$1" />
  </rewriter>

</configuration>
```

I want it re-write only .aspx files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url attribute in the rewrite element is a [.Net regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), at the moment the expression you have matches anything under ~/pages/. If you only want to match .aspx files the simplest thing to do is change it to:

```
<rewrite url="~/pages/(.+\.aspx)" to="~/default.aspx?pn=$1" />
```